# Command for clicking on the items of a Tkinter Treeview widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, treeview, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI with Tkinter, and a major part of the GUI is two Treeview objects. I need the contents of the `Treeview` objects to *change* when an item (i.e. a directory) is *clicked twice*.

If Treeview items were buttons, I'd just be able to set `command` to the appropriate function. But I'm having trouble finding a way to create `"on_click"` behavior for Treeview items.

What Treeview option, method, etc, enables me to bind a command to particular items and execute that command `"on_click"`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you want something to happen when the user double-clicks, add a binding to `"<Double-1>"`. Since a single click sets the selection, in your callback you can query the widget to find out what is selected. For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview()
        self.tree.pack()
        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text="Item %s" % i)
        self.tree.bind("<Double-1>", self.OnDoubleClick)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
        item = self.tree.selection()[0]
        print("you clicked on", self.tree.item(item,"text"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Answer (score 26):

The previous solution fails when multiple elements are selected and the user uses `SHIFT+CLICK` (at least on a Mac).

Here is a better solution:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview()
        self.tree.pack()
        for i in range(10):
            self.tree.insert("", "end", text="Item %s" % i)
        self.tree.bind("<Double-1>", self.OnDoubleClick)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def OnDoubleClick(self, event):
        item = self.tree.identify('item',event.x,event.y)
        print("you clicked on", self.tree.item(item,"text"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old but this code will also print multiple selected item in a treeview.

```
def on_double_click(self, event):
    item = self.tree.selection()
    for i in item:
        print("you clicked on", self.tree.item(i, "values")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar functionality on a Treeview and overcome the issue with row selection on click by binding the event to be on click release. As you will have to release your click eventually :P my code looks like something below:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

<codehere>

TreeView.bind('<Double-1>', function1) # If you want bind function1 on double click
    
TreeView.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', myfunction2) # If you want bind function2 on single click (on release click)
```