# How to store in variables current row selection within tree widget to query a database using python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I wonder if it is possible to store in variables the contents from a tree widget row (when it is selected with the mouse) see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx0zQ.jpg). Basically I want to sync my tree with a database, every time when I insert or delete an element in my tree, my database needs to auto update. 
    With the insert part it is  not a problem , because I have entry widgets, but I don't know how to manage the delete part. Therefore, I wonder if it is possible to do this with some cursor selection function. 
   I have been trying for a very long time to find a solution for this, I would really appreciate if someone can help me with some hints

Code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

class cards(tkinter.Frame): 
def __init__(self, parent):

    tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent=parent
    self.parent.geometry("800x500")
    self.initialize_user_interface()

def initialize_user_interface(self):

    self.parent.title("cards")       
    self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.parent.config(background="lavender")

    self.Card_label = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text = "Card type:")
    self.Card_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.parent)
    self.Card_label.place(x=5,y=5)
    self.Card_entry.place(x=70,y=5)

    self.SN_label = tkinter.Label(self.parent, text = "SN:")
    self.SN_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.parent)
    self.SN_label.place(x=5,y=40)
    self.SN_entry.place(x=70,y=40)

    self.submit_button = tkinter.Button(self.parent, text = "Insert", command = self.insert_data)
    self.submit_button.place(x=210,y=15)
    self.exit_button = tkinter.Button(self.parent, text = "Exit", command = self.exit)
    self.exit_button.place(x=270,y=15)

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview( self.parent, columns=('Card Type', 'SN'))
    self.tree.heading('#0', text='Nr.')
    self.tree.heading('#1', text='Card Type')
    self.tree.heading('#2', text='SN')
    self.tree.column('#1', stretch=tkinter.YES)
    self.tree.column('#2', stretch=tkinter.YES)
    self.tree.column('#0', stretch=tkinter.YES)
    self.tree.place(x=0,y=100)
    self.treeview = self.tree

    self.i = 1
def exit(self):
      self.master.destroy()

def insert_data(self):

    self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text=str(self.i), values=(self.Card_entry.get(), self.SN_entry.get()))
    self.i = self.i + 1         

def main():
root=tkinter.Tk()
d=cards(root)
root.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
main()
```

Comment: you can `bind` mouse click - see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3794268/1832058

Comment: @furas If i use this on my code, it will always return only the element from the "Nr." column (ex: 1,2,3,etc.) and I also want to return the items on"Card type" and " SN" columns.

Comment: use `self.tree.item(item)` (without `"text"`) or `self.tree.item(item, "values")` to get all data in row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
    for item in self.tree.selection():
        print(self.tree.item(item, "text"))
        print(self.tree.item(item, "values"))
        #print(self.tree.item(item))
```

to see data from all selected rows - you can select more than one row.

You can use it in function assigned to button
or you can use `bind()` to assign function to mouse click on row.